# Method to check whether a number is prime or composite

Tags: java, algorithm, methods, composite

```
  public boolean isPrimeNum (int n) {
   boolean isPrime= true;
   for( int i=2; i<= n; i++) {
    if( n%i==0) {
     isPrime= false;
 }
isitPrime= true;

   if(isPrime)
    System.out.println("its a prime number");
   else
    System.out.println("its a composite number");   }
```

}

I have attempted to write this method to check whether a number is prime or composite, but I am not sure whether it is correct. Any kind of help would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you test it?

Comment: It is not even compilable, because the `return` statement is missing.

Comment: are you sure you have to increment `i` all the way to `n` value? if you're checking for example n=7, do you have to check by dividing it by all numbers up to 7 to check if it is prime?

Comment: @Azanx that seemed correct to me

Comment: @LipstickQueen `i` should be lower than `n`, because `i%n` for `i=n` will always return 0 (all numbers can be divided by itself). Also, there is no need to check for `i` higher than `n/2` (such operation will always return some remainder)

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not our responsibility to test your code for you. Test it yourself and ask if you encounter a specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your refactored code. Feel free to comment if you are having questions.

```
class PrimeChecker { //Has to be in a class
      public boolean isPrimeNum(int n) {
          boolean isPrime=true;
          for (int i=2; i < n; i++) { //Has to be i < n instead of i <= n, every number can be divided by itself
              if (n%i==0) {
                 isPrime=false;
                 break; //Note you can break then
              }
          } //You were missing this
          //Removed : isitPrime= true; makes absolutely no sense 
          if(isPrime) {
             System.out.println("its a prime number");
             return true; //Breaks, you wont need else anymore
          } //You were missing these again
          System.out.println("its a composite number");
          return false;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it a bit (very slight) more efficient by checking the modulo(%) till <=(n/2) as a number's biggest factor (excluding itself) will always be less than or equal to its half, ie, for(int i=2;i<=n/2;i++);
Oh and check for 2 and 3 separately:)

Answer (score -1):

You should google search for this type of questions. 
However I am answering an optimized way of finding prime numbers

```
 private static boolean isPrimeNum(int n){
    if(n==2 || n==3) return true;
    if(n%2==0 || n%3==0) return false;

        for(int i=5;i<=Math.sqrt(n);i=i+2){
            if(n%i==0) return false;

        }
    return true;
}
```